# Next js application is showing 404 when I try to land any page except home

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, custom-error-pages

I have deployed my next js application on the firebase. When I try to land any page directly except the home page, it's showing me the 404 page.

suppose, my app link is: example.com
and it has pages.

- Home
- about
- contact

When I try to visit example.com, it's showing the home as expected.
But when I try to visit example.com/about, then it's showing 404 page. But the thing is, when I visit example.com/about and reload the page manually, then the about page is showing as expected.

I have tried to deploy in firebase.

here is my script commands

```
"dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build && next export",
        "start": "next start",
```

Comment: could you add `firebase.json` to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

enable [`rewrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) in your **firebase.json** to redirect all requests to your index.html file .

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: for me all this does is serve the homepage on every route